# Using a global variable inside a function nested in a function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, global-variables, environment

I wonder why my code is not working.  I expected that it would return 11 and instead it creates an exception:

```
def f():

   counter = 1

   def f1():

      global counter

      counter += 1

   while True:

       f1()

       if counter>10:

           return(counter)

f()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-219-0ec059b9bfe1> in <module>()
----> 1 f()

<ipython-input-218-50c23b042204> in f()
      9         counter += 1
     10 
---> 11     f1()
     12 
     13     if counter>10:

<ipython-input-218-50c23b042204> in f1()
      7         global counter
      8 
----> 9         counter += 1
     10 
     11     f1()

NameError: name 'counter' is not defined
```

Since counter is declared a global variable and since it appears and defined in the surrounding environment of f1() --inside f()-- why I receive this error message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to increment the value of the global `counter` when it has not yet been given a value. The counter in the `f()` function is in a different scope and a different variable then your global `counter` in the `f1()` function.

You have to specify `global counter` for each scope that you will be using this global variable in. So by doing this it should fix your issue:

```
def f():
    global counter
    counter = 1

    def f1():
        global counter
        counter += 1

    f1()
    if counter > 10:
        return(counter)

f()
```

I would also suggest avoiding declaring functions within functions without good reason and from using globals because it can complicate the program. It would be better practice to instead pass `counter` as an argument to the function and return the result.

An example without using globals or nested functions:

```
def f():
    counter = 1
    result = f1(counter)

    if result > 10:
        return(result)

def f1(argument):
    argument += 1
    return argument

f()
```

Comment: You don't need to create `global`. You can use `nonlocal` https://stackoverflow.com/a/72566012/7284582

Answer (score 7):

It's not a global variable. In the global scope it doesn't exist. Use `nonlocal` instead of `global`.

Comment: This makes more sense since and is cleaner. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables